# Facebook API call insufficient privileges

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-apps

I'm testing Facebook Ad Manager API from commandline curl.

To get the access token, I did this API call:

```
curl \
   -F "client_id=$APP_ID" \
   -F "client_secret=$APP_SECRET" \
   -F "grant_type=client_credentials" \
   https://graph.facebook.com/$API_VERSION/oauth/access_token
```

It returned successfully.

But then, when making this call to create a new campaign:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/$API_VERSION/act_$ACCOUNT_ID/campaigns?name=$CAMPAIGN_NAME&objective=VIDEO_VIEWS&status=PAUSED&access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I always get an error:

```
(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action
```

I guess that it must be caused because I did not granted the right permissions to the App. It is just a test app and I cannot find how to grant these permissions.

Thankyou very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for permissions with the `scope` parameter. It is a comma separated list of permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Permissions for ads are `ads_read` and `ads_management`.

Here´s more information about building a manual login flow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: Thankyou for yur answer, I modified the `access_token` request to add the `scope` parameter, but the response keeps unchanged...

Comment: make sure you get asked for the permission(s) in the authorization process, that´s the important thing, and check out the last link in my answer to make sure your manual login flow is correct.